# How to create a Map in C++ that associates functions to parameters?

Tags: c++

Consider that you want to call 100 functions sequentially.

I want to create a map that holds function pointers and function parameters, so that i can iterate the map and call each function with the associated parameters.

The arguments are of different type, arity and return type. Is it possible to implement such map in C++?

Pseudocode

```
for function in map
    // call the function with the arguments from the map
    function(map[function])
```

Comment: Yes it is. Please be more specific too make it easier to give a more specific answer. The arguments are of any type and functions are of any arity?

Comment: Yes, the arguments are of any arity and the return types are not the same.

Comment: Unless you are intending to do lookups in the map to find the parameters for a specific function then using a map makes no sense. If all you are doing is iterating then just use a vector.

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve by using that map? THink what happens if you make your example more complete by adding pseudo to fill the map, then you fill the map and then then look up the stuff from the map to call the functions, what do you gain compared to simply call the functions?

Comment: what do you want to do with the return values? This question really is too broad

Comment: The way to do this (assuming it's worth doing) is to define a base class called `Action` say, which has a single pure virtual method `void perform() = 0`. Then derive classes from that for the particular actions you want to store and later execute.

Comment: In your pseudocode you ignore the return value, in the comments you imply they matter. How you intend deal with heterogenous types in a homogenous manner is kind of crucial to your design. So some specifics on that is needed.

Comment: Why not use a lambda + `std::function` to bind the parameters?

Comment: Wouldn't filling the map require just the same effort than simply writing one single function that calls all the other ones? So why not just do the latter???

Comment: Yes, I realized that such data structure would not bring true benefits. I wanted to automate somehow calling those functions because it would be tedious to write all the calls by hand. Even if i would automate the calls with a for loop, I would still have to build the data structure by hand.

Comment: *I want to create a map that holds function pointers* -- That's your first mistake.  If anything, it should be a map of function *objects*, or functors, not function pointers.  The way this is usually solved is by moving the parameters away from the actual function being called, and instead have those parameters be part of the function object (set them on construction of the function object).

Comment: @AdrianNegru [See this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acc68ec62c4d6d7f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this question is too broad. Therefore, there are too many possible solutions. Also, I really wonder why you need this kind of map of functions. I'm sure if you explained your problem, many would advise you a different kind of solution.

That said, I find the subject interesting, and tried to implement a possible solution to your problem.

As the subject is very broad and the question not specific enough, I had to make some decisions (also based on the comments):

- I used a `set` instead of a `map` as I had no idea what the (key,value) of the map should be.
- I just print out the results (assuming the result is printable), as I have no idea what to do with the result.
- Instead of function pointers, I used function objects.
- As I was not able to fully understand the pseudo code, the functions are called by an invoke function.

Modifying the below example code should allow you to get what you exactly want. The below code is just an example of what kind of ingredients you might need.

**GenericFunction and the set**

You can only save one type in a `set` (or `map`), so you need some `GenericFunction` class:

```
class GenericFunction
{
public:
    virtual ~GenericFunction() = default;

    virtual void invoke() const = 0; // the method to invoke the function
};
```

Now, you can define a `set` which will contain pointers to `GenericFunction` objects:

```
std::set<GenericFunction*> myFcts;
```

**Specific function class**

Next, let's implement the specific function class which derives from the `GenericFunction` class. The goal of this class is to store the function and arguments of your choice, and to provide an implementation of the `invoke` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename Fct, typename ... Args>
class MyFct : public GenericFunction
{
public:
    MyFct(Fct fct, Args&& ... args) :
        _fct { std::move(fct) },
        _args { std::forward<Args>(args)... }
    {}

    void invoke() const override { std::cout << std::apply(_fct,_args) << std::endl; }

private:
    Fct _fct;
    std::tuple<Args ...> _args;
};
```

**Testing: sum function**

For testing, let's write a simple sum function:

```
template <typename T>
auto sum(T a)
{
    return a;
}

template <typename F, typename ... R>
auto sum(F first, R ... rest)
{
    return first + sum(rest...);
}
```

**main function**

We can now use the above code like this:

```
#include <set>

int main()
{
    // function wrapper
    auto sum_wrapper = [](auto&&... args)
    {
        return sum(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };

    // create a specific function
    MyFct myf1(sum_wrapper, 1, 2.33/*, add the args of your choice*/);

    // create another specific function        
    MyFct myf2(sum_wrapper, 10, 2.33/*, add the args of your choice*/);

    // create the set
    std::set<GenericFunction*> myFcts { &myf1, &myf2 };

    // call the functions
    for (const auto& f : myFcts)
        f->invoke();

    return 0;
}
```